# Why am i getting authorization errors while using a personal access token?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the Visual Studio Team Services .NET libraries to perform source control through a class library of mine. I'm also using a personal access token for authentication, previously set through the VSTS web client.

I'm trying to perform basic actions like check in, out, adding pending changes, create folder mappings etc, and i'm getting an "attempted to perform an unauthorized operation" error when i previously add no problem doing these tasks. I was running my .dll on the server it's supposed to be running when it's done and because i was getting this error i tweaked a few lines of code and then just tested the whole thing on my machine again. It doesn't work anymore at all.

What's weird, though, is that when i try to change the working folder mapping for example, i get this error but the new local path gets assigned just fine.

Any reason why an authenticated VSTS user would have these problems?

Comment: You said that the new local path gets assigned file, what's the result if you change mapping for this new local path? Can you share the detail code here?

Answer (score 3):

Using **PAT** (personal access token) to authorize your .NET libraries, you should `VssBasicCredential`, such as below example:

```
string personalAccessToken = "bnsz6p2efh3vljhjoay4rnaznliygu9vngoqgcwel7gwlati8cxq";
VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", personalAccessToken);
```

More details, you can refer [.NET client libraries](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/samples#net-client-libraries).

Besides, you can also use **Alternate authentication credentials**. VSTS account -> security -> Alternate authentication credentials (https://account.visualstudio.com/_details/security/altcreds) -> Enable alternate authentication credentials -> set secondary username and password -> save.

[image]

Then you can authorize your .NET libraries by:

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("secondary username", "password for secondary username");
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://account.visualstudio.com"), credentials);
```